# Not to make a mockery of it, but

Tags: knowledge

[Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) reminds me of this:

> **0163507**

Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick google search of this number gives us a result

> [Whose Line Is It Anyway?](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0163507/) on IMDB. It was a comedy TV show.

This result and PSE might be related because

> of the fun they both contain. Many games were played on the TV show same as many questions are asked on PSE.

**EDIT:** As [kayzeroshort](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25056/kayzeroshort) pointed out in the comments that

> the show's slogan is "where everything's made up and the points don't matter." And surely many answers on many puzzles are made up and points don't really matter if we are having fun. ;)

Comment: the show's slogan is "where everything's made up and the points don't matter."
AND it stars Colin Mochrie ("mockery")